# How to keep the same page for different languages

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I have a WordPress site that uses qTranslate as the language and country selector. So far it is working great. My only issue right now is if I have to create or edit a page, I have to redo it over and over for the other countries. Is there a way to keep the same page for the different languages/countries?

Thank you.

I have tried to go to settings to find a solution but it doesn't look like qtranslate have this option

Answer (score 0):

For each language you just had to input the content in the respective language before saving. qTranslate has the LSB (Language Switch Button) which lets you enter different language content at same input fields.